# Resizing a Windroy Window

Tags: android, windows, resize, emulation, windroy

I am a big fan of [windroy](http://www.socketeq.com/), an [OSAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system_abstraction_layer) between Android and Windows. Apparent in all their marketing windowed/resizable mode is an option (observe image from their landing page), however when I start the product I am stuck in full screen. I've done my research and no one explicitly says how to leave full screen mode. I've also done some snooping in their configeration files and can't find a setting that matches. How does one re-size Windroy, Android for Windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Tested working on Windows 7**

Right-click **My Computer** > Click **Properties**

Click **Advanced system settings**

Click **Environment Variables**

Under **System Variables** click **New**

Input **Variable name:** WINDROY_RESOLUTION and **Variable value:** 800x600 then click **OK** 
Click **OK** then **Apply** then **OK**

Start Windroy and it will now have a 800x600 resolution.

Click [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIN0FqjURDI&amp=&ctp=CAIQpDAYACIT) for instruction with images or click [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIN0FqjURDI&amp=&ctp=CAIQpDAYACIT) to view video.

Answer (score 4):

According to the instructions on the Windroy download site for the version just released last week:

> Add window mode. The default is full screen mode. To set main window size, set an environment variable WINDROY_RESOLUTION=widthxheight. For example, WINDROY_RESOLUTION=800x600. 
>   But he doesn't tell you where or how to establish that variable. Nor did the developer add an option in the "Display" setting of Windroy to run windowed or full screen.

To me, that seems like the common-sense thing to have done, because a lot of people have been asking about this. I tried an .ini file, but that didn't work. (I'm running Windows 7 on a Dell PC with a widescreen monitor at 1366x768. I'd like to run Windroy windowed at 800x600, then scale that window anytime I need to.)

I wrote to the developer (socketeq) and received no reply. Where would that variable go? If it's in the Windows registry, how would I set it up? I'm no expert on hex or binary values. Is there a parameter or two I could add to the run command line in "Properties" box in Windows? I could use some help here, since this is the only issue that's keeping me from using Windroy. Thanks to anyone who can give me a straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

After multiple emails to the developer, he released a build today that takes an environment variable to change the resolution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share, to set the environment variable:

- At `Control Panel > Advance system settings > Press on 'Environment
  Variables'` button
- Under user variable section, press on `New button`
- Under variable name : type `(WINDROY_RESOLUTION), Variable value : 800x600`
- Press `OK` `3 times` to close the window.
- Restart `WINDROY application`.